# Maven - Filename too Long on Unzip

Tags: maven, zip, maven-3, filenames

I'm having a hell of a time installing maven 3.

I have the 3.0.4 source zip. I can't extract it, though, or I get a filename too long error on multiple jars in the zip. I'm running Windows 7.

I can't find ANYTHING about this anywhere else, and I'm starting to wonder if maybe I just have no idea how to install maven in the first place, not that there's something wrong with the zip.

Comment: Where do you try to install it? Try in c:\maven (rather than c:\my build tools\generic java tools\another directory\way out there\maven).

Comment: If you only need install Maven, just download apache-maven-3.0.4-bin.zip and follow the installation instructions in [its official page](http://maven.apache.org/download.html).

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same problem using windows 7 and trying to unzip the source zip from their official website.  To solve the problem I just followed ptyx's comment.  Instead of using C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation (like their site suggests) I just used C:/Maven

Answer (score 1):

You can 'fix' this by copying the archive in the root of one of your partitions, and then unarchive it into a folder in the same location.